# Angles Formed By The Hands Of A Clock

Tags: proof-writing, angle

Given a clock with hour, minute, and second hands that each move continuously (i.e., no “ticking” occurs), show whether there exists a time at which the lesser angle formed by each pair of the hands is $\frac{2 \pi}{3}$.

I ask this because, though I expect the solution to be fairly simple in retrospect, I have never before resolved a question of this form and do not know how to phrase any proof I had.

Comment: Is 4 O'clock good?

Comment: At 4:00, the lesser angle is between the second and minute hand: $0^\circ$.  If I'm interpreting this correctly, we'd need all $3$ hands equally spaced.

Comment: Before you can write the proof, you have to decide what you think the answer is.  Then you can write down your argument, and people can critique it for you. As it is, it sounds like you are just asking for someone to do your homework for you.  That said, I think a good approach is to start by determining the times at which the hour and minute hands form and angle of $120^\circ.$  Then it should be easy to figure out where the second hand is.

Comment: Perhaps this is useful. We can find the relationships between the pairs of hands. The following relations are in degrees:

$$\theta_H = 30 k_1 + \frac{\theta_M}{12}$$
$$\theta_M = 6 k_2 + \frac{\theta_S}{60}$$

where $\theta_H$, $\theta_M$, $\theta_S$ is the angle of the hour, minute, and seconds hand in degrees, respectively. $k_1$ and $k_2$ are some natural numbers.

Comment: Look at this diagram: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/The_Unit_Circle#/media/File:Unit_circle_angles.svg Find $2\pi/3$ (top left). You can see that this angle represent various times.

Comment: Starting at 12/0, between the hours and minutes hands you get it 22 times in 12 hours, once after and once before the hands meet again . You just need to find if the seconds hand is also having such angel for each of this cases - you may try it with equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First consider just the hour and minute hands.  They are together at noon.  How long does it take for the minute hand to gain $120^\circ$ on the hour hand?

The minute hand travels $6^\circ$ per minute, and the hour hand travels $\frac12^\circ$ per minute, so we need the solution to $$6m={m\over 2}+120$$ which gives $$m={240\over11} = 21{9\over11}\text{ minutes}$$  In $m$ minutes the minute hand travels $130{10\over11}^\circ$ and the hour hand travels $10{10\over11}^\circ.$  After $m$ minutes the minute hand is $120^\circ$ ahead.  After $2m$ minutes, it is $240^\circ$ ahead and the angle is $120^\circ$ again.  After $3m$ minutes, the hands are together again.  In any event, the only possibilities are $nm$ minutes after noon, for some integer $n$.

How far does the second hand travel in $m$ minutes?  Since it makes a whole number of revolutions in $21$ minutes, we only need be concerned with how far it travels in ${9\over11}$ minutes, which is $294{6\over11}^\circ.$

Looking at the fractions, we see that $n$ must be a multiple of $11$ if there is to be a whole number of degree between the minute hand and the second hand.  However, $$11m=240\text{ minutes } = 4\text{ hours,}$$ so the minute and second hands will coincide.

Thus, it is impossible.

Try doing the problem on a $24$-hour clock.

Answer (score 1):

There are 11 times in a 12 hour period when the hour hand an the minute hand form an angle of $\frac {2\pi}{3}$

Exactly 4:00 is one such time.

$H =(\frac {12}{11}k + \frac 23)$

Where $H$ is expressed in fractions of a revolution.  In these units the position of the minute hand is:

$M = \{12 H\} = \frac {1}{11} k$ where $\{x\} = x  - \lfloor x \rfloor $ or the fractional part of the number.

$S = \{60 M\} = {\frac {5}{11} k}$

$S-M$ will always be expressed as $\frac {1}{11}$'s and will never equal $\frac {1}{3}$